# I can't get Eclipse Luna to run on my mac

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-luna

I have a mac running os x 10.9.4 and I downloaded the newest version of eclipse.  It downloaded fine and installed but whenever I try to open it, I get an error that says, "Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product."  I downloaded and installed Java 7 and tried opening eclipse again only to get the same error.  Anybody know how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Try setting `JAVA_HOME` to your JDK 7 location as an env var before starting it, e.g. you could add this to your ~/.bash_profile file: `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the JDK installed. Google will point you to the runtime engine (JRE) if you search for a Java download (probably called `jre-7u67-macosx-x64`). Click on "show all Java downloads" in the download page and look for a link "looking for the JDK?" on the left . As of today, the JDK can be found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and should have a name like `jdk-7u67-macosx-x64` or `jdk-8u20-macosx-x64`. Both should be fine for a recent Eclipse Luna install.

If you want to run Eclipse Luna with Java 1.6, you can change the entry in the .ini file. Open the Eclipse application bundle by control-clicking and select "show contents". You will open a new finder window with a single folder "Contents". Open it, then open the folder "MacOS" and edit the file `eclipse.ini` which you will find inside. Change the line `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7` to `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6`. Close and save, and now Eclipse will run in a minimum configuration. But you really want to install the 1.7 JDK.

Answer (score -1):

For those using Mac OS X Mountain Lion (10.8)+. When you launch Eclipse for the first time, you may see the message "Eclipse can't be opened because it is from an unidentified developer."

To launch Eclipse for the first time, `press the control key, click on the Eclipse icon, and select Open.`